# selecting multiple days (10 days) in a calendar control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is a calendar control in asp.net

For selection mode, there is day, dayweek and dayweekmonth.

But I wanna select randomly like every monday for the selected month.. something like that.

For that, I need to do the custom method.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you want to randomly one weekday throughout the month, or a random assortment of days throughout, or... ?

Comment: have you google abt it..the first result i got is http://forums.asp.net/p/1032656/3645334.aspx

Comment: Yes, I already saw it. I dun quite understand abt that. I just paste the code and run it, 3 override functions got the errors stating that no suitable methods to override.

Comment: to jball --> i want randomly throughout the years

Comment: have a look at this post..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140766/datetimepicker-and-monthcalender-for-c-web/4141223#4141223

Comment: to Vj --> that question is also posted by me and that question solved datetimepicker issue. But what i want now is multiple dates selected in calendar control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forums.asp.net/p/1032656/3645334.aspx

copy the code from that page, create a new project. the type is webcustomcontrol.

paste it inside..

place the line below in the page u want to call that calendar..

@ Register Assembly="CustomControl" TagPrefix="cc" Namespace="CustomControl"

can use it already.